# flyspell does not start form the first try

Tags: flyspell, hunspell

I used `flyspell-mode` with `aspell` backend before, but now I want to make the transition to the `hunspell` so that I could use multiple dictionaries.

To do so, I added the following lines to the `init.el`:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)))
```

But when I enable `flyspell-mode` for the *first time in sesstion*, it throws error:

```
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(stringp nil)
```

When I enabling it again, it works just fine.

If I comment out all but the first line, flyspell fails every time.

How can I fix this?

GNU Emacs 26.1; 
Debian buster; 
flyspell 20181205;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I found that `ispell-minor-mode` needed `ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist` variable set. This code works:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US,ru_RU")
(setq ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist '(("en_US,ru_RU" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US,ru_RU") nil utf-8)))
```

Comment: Great!! That worked; I was searching for quite a while for that solution... Thanks